# Remove vertical space after \clearpage

Tags: clearpage

After using \clearpage, latex stretches the first column of my 2-column document, leaving a lot of white space. With the second column, the text is normal again. I can not post a code example, but I think this behavior is knwon. How do I force latex to simply continue the text without placing just 2 or 3 sentences in the first column?

Comment: a minimal working example for your question would be nice.

Comment: It works now with \clearpage\clearpage. Why does it need 2 commands?

Comment: It is not the default behaviour and how should we know what your document is doing? Make a complete example.